# Specify the node modules folder in angular 4 using mklink

Tags: angular, node-modules

Hello i want to change the location of my node_modules folder and after some research i didn't find a way to change it somewhere in angular-cli.json or in any other json.

I found this command :  `mklink /j node_modules S:\somepath\node_modules`

So like this i can make a reference to node_modules from another folder. The problem now is that `S:` is a mapped folder actually and not a real drive. And that mkLink command works only if it's a real drive like not a mapped folder.

Is it possible to make `mklink` work with mapped folders instead of a drive?

If i change the folder path to the actual drive path it works and i can compile the angular app. I would prefer having a mapped path instead of a drive but if it'sn ot possible i'll keep a drive path then.

I can create a link to a mapped folder using /d instead of /j but then angular doesn't compile anymore even with ng serve --preserve-symlinks.

PS: If there's any other way to externalize node_modules to a global folder i will accept it as a solution. I only need to find a way to remove node_modules from the app folder.